# How can i sort the list and print in react?

Tags: reactjs

How can i sort the data and print in react.
which libraries do i need to use ?
here is the data which is to be sorted field wise

```
data = [{
    key: 1,
    name: 'Steve',
    city: 'Paris',
  }, {
    key: 2,
    name: 'Tim',
    city: 'London',
  }, {
    key: 3,
    name: 'Stella',
    city: 'Bankok',
  }, {
    key: 4,
    name: 'John',
    city: 'Paris',
}];
```

Comment: by which field you want to sort? btw you don't need any lib for sorting you can directly do that by looping.

Comment: oh okay..by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control) for this.

Check this example:

```js
data = [{
    key: 1,
    name: 'Steve',
    city: 'Paris',
  }, {
    key: 2,
    name: 'Tim',
    city: 'London',
  }, {
    key: 3,
    name: 'Stella',
    city: 'Bankok',
  }, {
    key: 4,
    name: 'John',
    city: 'Paris',
}];

data.sort((a,b) => a.name > b.name);

console.log('updated data', data)
```